# Quartic Diophantine equation in two variables

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

How would one solve the following quartic Diophantine equation in two variables:

$$Ax^4 + Bx^3 + Cx^2 + Dx + Ey^2 + Ey = 0$$

where A, B, C, D, E are known integers and $x$, $y$ are unknown integers to be solved?

Thanks,

Comment: Already the case $A=0$ is an enormous subject (elliptic curves).

Comment: Good to know.  Thanks.

Comment: In fact, when $A\neq 0$, this is still an elliptic curve. See L. Washington, Elliptic Curves: Number Theory and Cryptography, page 37.

Comment: Transform a quartic into an elliptic curve: [Birational Equivalence of Diophantine Equations and Elliptic Curves](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1592599/318073), then look it up in [LMFDB](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Write the equation in the form

$$\text{quadratic in y } = \text{ quartic in }x.$$

If the quartic has a repeated root, then this equation cuts 
out a curve of (geometric) genus zero, which admits a
rational parameterization (if not over $\mathbb Q$ then over
an explicit finite extension), and so finding the integral points
should be straightforward.

E.g. $y^2 = x^3$ admits the parameterization $x = t^2,y=t^3$,
and hence integral solutions are given by $(t^2,t^3)$ with $t$
an integer.

If the quartic does not have a repeated root, then, as noted
in the comments, the equation cuts out a curve of (geometric) genus one, 
and a [theorem of Siegel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siegel%27s_theorem_on_integral_points) states that
it has only finitely many integral solutions.

To learn more about this, you should look at a textbook on elliptic curves,
of which there are many available.  Silverman's graduate text is the most
standard reference, although the book of Silverman and Tate is perhaps a better entry-point if Silverman's text seems at too high a level.