# How do third-degree polynomials arise when dealing with ellipses?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I am not familiar with elliptical integrals on an academic level, but I came across them as solutions to certain integrals and did some general reading. Why would solving a seemingly 2 dimensional and nearly circular geometric problem yield solutions that have third degree polynomials? And how does a real ellipse relate to a complex Riemann surfaces?

Comment: A complex compact Riemann surface is a algebraic curve, and curves of genus $1$ are called `elliptic curves`. They're related to elliptic functions, some of these functions are involved in the computation of the length of an elliptic arc.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral "elliptic integrals originally arose in connection with the problem of giving the arc length of an ellipse" Elliptic integrals being a function of two parameters only enforces that notion, since an ellipse has both a major and minor axis. If I looked an ellipse...where would obtain a third degree polynomial in the solution to any of its geometric properties? it doesn't seem very intuitive, I would think it still has something to do with quadratic or maybe quartic polynomials.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the answers to [Birational Equivalence of Diophantine Equations and Elliptic Curves](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1591990/birational-equivalence-of-diophantine-equations-and-elliptic-curves) and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/239746/birationally-transforming-a-quartic-elliptic-curve.