# Solving simultaneous (non linear) integer equations (a bit like conics)

Tags: diophantine-equations

I'm looking for all solutions, (x,y,s,t) in the integers, for the two simultaneous equations...
$$
7x^2 - y^2 = 3s^2\\
7y^2 - x^2 = 3t^2
$$
I have two solutions $(x,y,s,t) = (2,1,3,1)$ and $(751,422,1121,477)$.

I'm also interested in solving the more general cases...
$$
Ax^2 + By^2 = Cs^2\\
Ay^2 + Bx^2 = Ct^2
$$
where $A + B = 2C$

Is there a heading I can search under for more info?

Thanks.

Comment: To avoid an extra condition, a more compact way to express the general case would be $$\begin{split} 2Ax^2 + 2By^2 = (A+B)s^2\\2B x^2 + 2A y^2 = (A+B) t^2\end{split}$$

Answer (score 2):

There are an infinite number of solutions, but they get large quite quickly. Solving this system is a standard application of elliptic curves.

The quadric $7x^2-y^2=3s^2$ has the simple solution $x=1, y=2, s=1$, which allows us to find the parametric solution $x=3k^2-6k+7, y=2(3k^2-7)$.

Substituting into $7y^2-x^2=3t^2$ gives the quartic
\begin{equation*}
t^2=81k^4+12k^3-418k^2+28k+441
\end{equation*}
which has an obvious rational point when $k=0$, and so is birationally equivalent to an elliptic curve.

Standard methods find this curve to be
\begin{equation*}
v^2=u^3-97u^2+2352u
\end{equation*}
with
\begin{equation*}
k=\frac{6v-u}{3(9u-448)}
\end{equation*}

The elliptic curve has $7$ finite torsion points at $(0,0)$, $(48,0)$, $(49,0)$, $(42,\pm 42)$ and $(56, \pm 56)$. It also has rank $1$ with generator $(21,126)$.
This generator gives $k=-35/37$, and hence the second solution quoted.

Doubling the generator gives the following solution
\begin{equation*}
x=124344271, \, y=56190422, \, s=187147999, \,t=47046243
\end{equation*}

Further computation can give more solutions.

Allan Macleod

Comment: I found the same answer and that was through your [very helpful guide](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1591990/birational-equivalence-of-diophantine-equations-and-elliptic-curves), you might have noticed an upvote earlier haha. Leaving as a comment as other might  find it useful.

Comment: Thanks for that nice informative answer. I see I need to get into elliptic curves. i find this stuff jolly interesting

Answer (score 2):

The general case of the OP,
\begin{align}
Ax^2+By^2 &=Cs^2\\
Ay^2+Bx^2 &=Ct^2
\end{align}
with,
\begin{align}
A &=(p+q)^2-2q^2\\
B &=(p-q)^2-2q^2\\
C &= \,p^2-q^2
\end{align}
where the OP used $(p,q) = (2,1)$ so $(A,B,C) = (7,-1,3)$ leads to an elliptic curve with rank at least $1$ for any $(p,q)$ with $|p| \ne |q|$ and $pq \ne 0$. This gives an infinite number of possible parametric solutions using $(p,q)$. One such is

\begin{equation*}
x=q(3p^8-4p^6q^2+14p^4q^4+4p^2q^6-q^8)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
y=p(p^8-4p^6q^2-14p^4q^4+4p^2q^6-3q^8)
\end{equation*}

The derivation is a standard (if boring) computation, using a symbolic algebra package.

Comment: That's great. Thanks for taking the time to post  it.

Answer (score 0):

With regard to the general problem
\begin{equation*}
2Ax^2+2By^2=(A+B)s^2 \hspace{2cm} 2Ay^2+2Bx^2=(A+B)t^2
\end{equation*}
solutions do NOT exist for any combination of $A$ and $B$.

For example, for $A=5, B=-1$, there are no solutions since the quadric $5x^2-y^2=2s^2$ is not locally soluble at the prime $p=5$.

Allan Macleod

Comment: Thanks for that. I suspected that might be the case. Although my A and B have further restrictions which, I think, mean I will always have solutions. In case you're curious A = Q + P and B = Q - P, where Q = (p^2 - q^2) and P = 2*p*q.

Comment: It would be nice to know the reason for these extra conditions.

Comment: Allan MacLeod,  yes sorry, I should have said. The problem I'm looking at is:  Given co-prime integers, (p,q), of opposite parity find all (u,v) and (x,y), with equal norms, such that p + iq rotates (and scales) u + iv, u - iv, x + iy and x - iy so that their areas 'sum' to zero. In what I posted here, s = u + v and t = u - v. It's connected with my investigation into the unsolved problem of 3x3 magic square of squares.

Answer (score 0):

Above equation shown below:

$\begin{split} Ax^2 + By^2 = Cs^2\\B x^2 + A y^2 = Ct^2\end{split}$

The above simultaneous equation has parametric solution given by Mr. Seiji Tomita & is shown below.

$x$ = $4(5625m^{14}$-1075$m^{12}$$n^2$+9509$m^{10}$$n^4$+2553$m^8n^6$-101$m^6$$n^8$-137$m^4$$n^{10}$+
      7$m^2$$n^{12}$+3$n^{14}$)$m^2$

$y$ = ($n^2$+3$m^2$)(-$n^{14}$-$m^2$$n^{12}$+27$m^4$$n^{10}$+427$m^6$$n^8$+2173$m^8$$n^6$-8291$m^{10}$$n^4$+
       16425$m^{12}$$n^2$+5625$m^{14}$)

$s$ = (-$n^2$+5$m^2$)(-$n^{14}$-$m^2$$n^{12}$+27$m^4$$n^{10}$-597$m^6$$n^8$-4995$m^8$$n^6$-7267$m^{10}$$n^4$-9175$m^{12}$$n^2$+5625$m^{14}$)

$t$ = 4($n^{14}$+5$m^2$$n^{12}$-83$m^4$$n^{10}$-271$m^6$$n^8$-269$m^8$$n^6$-
     6049$m^{10}$$n^4$+6175$m^{12}$$n^2$+16875$m^{14}$)mn

Where $(A,B,C)=[(16m^2),(n^2-9m^2),(7m^2+n^2)]$

For $(m,n)=(2,1)$  we have

$(x,y,s,t)=[(1570223344),(1969901167),(870604529),(2363928872)]$

$(A,B,C)=(64,-35,29)$

Seiji Tomita's article can be viewed on his web site

"Computational number theory" article # 306 & the link is given below:

http://www.maroon.dti.ne.jp/fermat/eindex.html

Comment: Please use $\LaTeX$. You can look here how to use it: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thanks for that. I've had a quick look at your site and will take a longer look once I get time. Only one thing, in my case I have A + B = 2*C. To be specific, A = Q + P, B = Q - P, C = Q, Q = (p^2 - q^2) and P = 2*p*q. Anyway, I'll take a good look at the work on your site before attempting to find a solution my specific case.

Answer (score 0):

Above equation shown below:

$Ax^2 + By^2 = Cs^2\\
Ay^2 + Bx^2 = Ct^2$

"OP" want's parametric solution for variable's $(x,y,s,t)$. Allen Macleod has kindly provided solution only for variable's $(x,y)$. By extension, the parametric solution given by Allen Macleod for variables $(s,t)$ would be:

$s=(p-q)(p^8+16p^5q^3+14p^4q^4+16p^3q^5+q^8)$

$t=(p+q)(p^8-16p^5q^3+14p^4q^4-16p^3q^5+q^8)$

For $(p,q)=(2,1)$ we get back solution given by "OP" as

$(A,B,C)=(7,-1,3)$

$(x,y,s,t)=(751,422,1121,477)$

Answer (score 0):

Above equation shown below:

$Ax^2 + By^2 = Cs^2\\
Ay^2 + Bx^2 = Ct^2$

Above has solution:

$(x,y,s,t)= (36,31,41,24)$

$(A,B,C)=(144,-77,67)$

For detail's see the below mentioned link:

[Non-trivial solutions of $Ax^2+By^2=Cs^2$ and $Ay^2+Bx^2=Ct^2$, where $A=p^2-q^2+2pq$, $B=p^2-q^2-2pq$, $C=p^2-q^2$ for integer $p$ and $q$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3117678)